# Is it possible to rsync .bash_aliases with an alias? (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: bash, alias, ubuntu-14.04

I want to set up an alias that allows me to, among other things backup .bash_aliases to an external hard drive. Here's what I have so far that I thought should do the trick:

`alias alibackup="rsync -av --delete '/home/usrname/.bash_aliases' '/media/usrname/External Drive Name/aliasbackup/'"`

At the moment I have this line in the .bash_alias file but when I type in `alibackup` to terminal my command isn't found. The was definitely saved and closed and I still have that line in there when I reopen it.

I've tried other alias commands from the same file and they are working fine.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: If it is I can take it over there unless someone else can transfer it.

Comment: It's not really an Ubuntu or rsync question. This is just about `bash`. Maybe http://unix.stackexchange.com/ would be a good place for it

Comment: Looks like that answer was correct. It just needed . ~/.bash_aliases I was testing new things and then forgot to change back the alias I was using after that. Thanks Ewan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reload your .bash_aliases whenever you change it.  This normally happens when you sign in.  Do this to force it:

```
. ~/.bash_aliases
```

Comment: Typed that into terminal and then called my alias. Still nothing. Is that what you meant? I also already opened and closed the shell several times.

Comment: I'll edit the question and provide the entire file with more detail.

Comment: Aha. Your question talks about `.bash_alias`, but it should be `~/.bash_aliases`. Is this the problem, @Fernando ?